# Passing FlatList title

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln6uY.png)enter image description hereI have a flatlist of five items. when I click any of list item it opens a new screen that just consist a textinput box and a save button. Now I want to get title from list item that I have clicked. please help me how can I pass list title that I have clicked to another component.[enter link description here](https://snack.expo.io/@anisahmad/list)

Comment: How are you changing screens? `With react-navigation`?

Comment: Generally you pass data as props to other components. Perhaps if you include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example we can provide more assistance. Also useful, [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have added image as description. please find that

Answer (score 0):

you can write the function like this :

GetDATA(item){

this.props.navigation.replace("Next_Component", { Title: item.title }) }

}
and use TouchableOpacity tag in the Flatlist as a father view, like this :

<TouchableOpacity
style={{
flexDirection: 'row',
padding: 2,
width: "76%",
}}

onPress= {() =>{ this.GetDATA(item)}}

> 

so by this method you can get item details like name or another attributes.

Comment: can you please check image as description about

Comment: yes, check the code I have written :

https://snack.expo.io/DjUZqzPIQ

That code, I have written, you can just pass single text to other class

Comment: I am implementing functional component on all my app not any class base component. how can we do this in functional component?

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@anisahmad/nervous-ramen

Here is my RecordEvent screen